# retrieve value inside the div separately using the for loop or $.each

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="head-text">
    <div class="body-text">
        <div class="line1">
            This is line one1
        </div>
        <div class="line2">
            This is line one1
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="body-text">
        <div class="line1">
            This is line one2
        </div>
        <div class="line2">
            This is line one2
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="body-text">
        <div class="line1">
            This is line one3
        </div>
        <div class="line2">
            This is line one3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is I want to retrieve the texts individually. I've tried using loops but I'm either getting the whole thing or only the first thing.

For eg: if I need to retrieve the text "This is line one2" in a loop, then how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body-text').each(function() {
    $(this).children('div').each(function() {
        myText = $(this).text();
    }
}
```

UPDATE: It doesn't sound like you want a loop at all based on your comments. You may simply want, for example:

```
$('.body-text:nth-child(3)').children('.line2').text();
```

Comment: Thanks. I was missing a dot, too. Tired eyes. :-)

Comment: No this is not working actually. I'm getting the values again and again. My necessity is when i click on 
    <div class="line1">
        This is line one3
    </div>
i need an output displaying "This is line one3" 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("div[class^=line]").each(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

And if you need all of them in an array :

```
var arr = $("div[class^=line]").map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
          }).get();
```

If you need the alert on click: http://jsfiddle.net/mzZR8/

```
$("div[class^=line]").click(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Not a bad approach. I'd probably put .body-text in there as a parent selector to be sure you don't pick up other similar classes on the page.

Comment: I want to display onclick of the div "body-text". I mean on clicking the whole "body-text" div, i need to get the text as "This is line one3" or "This is line one1", etc
Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking the function to arbitrarily return one of the two child elements' text when the parent is clicked. That can't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
$(".body-text").click(function(evt){
   alert($(evt.target).text());
});
```

The "evt" argument allows you to access the "target" which is what you are clicking on directly.

Heres a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dtwigs/38QuN/)